# Path expected for join hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a problem with hibernate `HQL` queries and simple INNER JOIN

```
String hql = "SELECT NEW es.criteria.crc.model.queryObjects.NameQuery(pf.name) FROM Person as p INNER JOIN PhisicalPerson as pf WHERE pf.idPersona = p.idPersona";
    return personService.query(hql);
```

My Java file has the following code:

```
public class NameQuery{
    private String name;

    public NameQuery(String name) {
        super();
        this.name= name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }
}
```

I recieve the following error in console:

```
   Caused By: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join!
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an association (`@OneToMany`, `@OneToOne`) between `Person` and `PhisicalPerson`. Having such an association you don't need the `where` clause

```
SELECT NEW es.criteria.crc.model.queryObjects.NameQuery(pf.name) 
    FROM Person as p INNER JOIN p.pf
```

In the example `pf` is a property of `Person`, associated to `PhisicalPerson`.

```
class Person {

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "person")
    private PhisicalPerson pf;

}

class PhisicalPerson {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_person")
    private Person person;

}
```

Comment: Thansk , @v.ladynev how I can use One to One with this sample?